# wget/curl in C#

Tags: c#, curl, mono, network-programming, wget

I'm writing a scraper in C# and I'd like to download some data to files and submit some forms. I've been using `wget` and `curl` so far for that. How would I do that in C# (on Linux)? (I mean a library for that, not calling shell commands via `system()` or whatnot).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), which is the simplest interface for downloading resources in .NET. If you need more control on the requests look at [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

For WebClient, just instantiate an instance, and call one of the Download methods which fits your needs:

```
var cli = new WebClient();
string data = cli.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 3):

[`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) is one of the .NET classes for retrieving web content.

A good library to parse the HTML is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) that can also directly download the page.